# Selenium @test (dependsOnMethods) error

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have some simple code like this for testing testng

```
@Test
public void start(){
    System.out.print( "st" );
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "start")
public void  middle (){
    System.out.print( "middle" );
```

But `dependsOnMethods` show as an error. However, I import JUnit in Library when I type

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods)
```

And there is no error. But at:

```
 @Test(dependsOnMethods="start" )
```

It shows a `dependsOnMethods` error here

Comment: import testng  instead of junit.

Comment: what is the error? Please share error logs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven framework, you can simply add maven dependency in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
```